# Excel VBA switch statement based on the value of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a cell(A2) with an Integer value in it(5). I would like a switch statement that looks at the cell and then if the value of that cell is greater than 50000 do something, if the value is less than 50000 do something.

Here is my code that does not work, it says "overflow" for the line of code `threshold = 50000`:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim state As Integer
    Dim threshold As Integer

    threshold = 50000
    state = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value

    Select Case state
        Case state < threshold
            'Do something
            Debug.Print (state)
        Case Is >= threshold
            'Do something
            Debug.Print (state)
        End Select

End Sub
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:
`Sheet1.Range.Value("$A$2")`

using `Select Case`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim state As Integer
    state = CInt(Sheet1.Range("$A$2"))
    Select Case state
        Case Is > Target.Value
            Debug.Print "less than " & state
        Case Is < Target.Value
            Debug.Print "greater than " & state
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Equals"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Using `if` statement

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim state As Integer
    state = CInt(Sheet1.Range("$A$2"))
    If Target.Value < state Then
        Debug.Print "less than " & state
    ElseIf Target.Value > state Then
        Debug.Print "greater than " & state
    Else
        Debug.Print "Equals"
    End If
End Sub
```

**POST_EDIT:**
50000 is too big for an `Integer` data type, so dimension it as a `Long` data type to avoid the **Overflow**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim threshold As Long
    threshold = 50000
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is >= threshold
            Debug.Print "greater or equal " & threshold
        Case Is < Target.Value
            Debug.Print "smaller than " & threshold
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Can't calculate! Error"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: you want to dimension your variable as `Long` type not `Integer`

Answer (score 2):

Your Range statement is wrong

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim state As Integer

    state = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value

    Select Case state
        Case Is < 5
            'Do something
            Debug.Print (state)
        Case Is > 5
            'Do something

        End Select

End Sub
```

you didn't mention what to do if state = 5?

Comment: Could I do: `Case Is >= 5`?